# Unit testing HQL query

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, unit-testing, nhibernate

I have something like a HQL-query factory, which produces plain string HQL-queries. How can I unit-test for syntax errors, without doing integration testing with the database by actually executing the query over something?

Best option would be to call some magic VerifyHql() method, or to maybe use it somewhere and catch some meaningful parse exception or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to test a query without a database to query, so these should be tested using integration tests. However, you can [use an in memory SQLite database](http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing) instead of hitting a real server. There's a [NuGet SQLite package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) available.

Comment: Jamie, you've got the point! Denis, you can download NHibernate code and observe the `HQL` testing. (..Testing *Data* are flushed in the DB, before any `HQL` test is executed...)

Comment: Well, I still think it makes sense in certain scenarios. One example would be for testing highly complex HQL queries which are dynamically constructed (rare but I've had to deal with one which was very complex). Although there are very big amount of tests for this query which test it against an in-memory database, still I would see some value for having a quick syntax test as well. It goes into same direction why I would say that tests for checking integrity of mappings are valuable as well, without having an integration test for every mapped detail.